# Does Microsoft Azure Active Domain Service (ADDS) supports PTA?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-active-directory

I have an on-prem Active Directory. I am thinking to Setup an ADDS for my VMs in Azure and sync my local AD with ADDS with Azure AD Connect. That makes an own DC-Satellit (One-way trust) in my Cloud obsolte. My idea so far.

Question: Does ADDS Supports PTA (Pass-through-Authentication)? I am in need to keep the on-prem credentials out of the Cloud.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand the purpose of Pass-Through-Authentication.

[Pass-Through-Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-pass-through-authentication) allows your users to sign-in to on-premises **and cloud services** using same username/password combination. This works via an Agent which is installed near your on-premises domain controller(s).

[Azure AD DS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-synchronization) on the other hand synchronizes user identities from your on-premises **over Azure AD** to managed domain in Azure Virtual Network. The only way for this to work, is to have [Azure AD Connect Password Hash Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-implement-password-hash-synchronization) configured. The latter is really neat feature and I recommend everyone to use it.

Now, if you have all this. PTA only help you when your user wants to authenticate to a cloud service (i.e. O365 / Azure, etc.). And it works over the agent which is installed by your on-premises domain controller. So yes, if you configure PTA and you use an Azure VM to try to sign-in to a cloud service, PTA will work. But not because of Azure AD DS. PTA has nothing to do with Azure AD DS.